# JASidepanels not showing navigationbutton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, jasidepanels

I am trying to implement the `JASidePanels` in my project using `storyboard`. You can see my storyboard over here.

[image]

The problem is that I don't see the button in the navigationbar to reveal the leftpanel. In my RootViewController I've this in code.

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
    [self setRightPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"]];
        self.shouldResizeLeftPanel = YES;
    self.shouldResizeRightPanel = YES;
    [self setRightFixedWidth:300.0f];
    [self setLeftFixedWidth:300.0f];

}
```

I've followed the steps that they say on the [github page](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels).
Also when I try to embed the `RootviewController` inside a `navigationController`. It is showing the navigationBar but not the `barbutton item`.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 9):

Embed your center UIViewController in storyBoard into UINavigationController, for example:

1. Select UIViewController on StoryBoard
2. Select Xcode menu item Editor - Embed In - Navigation Controller
3. Select new UINavigationController's Identity Inspector (Alt-Command-3)
4. Give unique name to StoryBoard ID e.g. myCenterController
5. Use that name to create center panel

   [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myCenterController"]];

So you don't actually set viewController as centerPanel, but a navigation controller containing your viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using swift 2.2 and I couldn't either see the navigation button.

I'm using storyboards; so I created:

- **MainViewController** -> this is going to be the main container
- **LeftMenuViewController** -> this is the left menu
- **ProductsViewController** -> this is going to be inside *MainViewController*

So in `MainViewController`, I set up my VC as follows:

```
self.leftPanel = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftMenuViewController") //for left menu and

self.centerPanel = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductsViewController"))!)
```

Adding `UINavigationController.init` will solve the problem, and you will see the navigation button in the center panel.